# Activity permission Denial

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, permissions

I've encountered a strange permission denial in my Android app, here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="test.mymax"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".Test_mymaxActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="A_Info"></activity>
        <activity android:name="A_Info_Refresh"></activity>
        <activity android:name="_TagConnector"></activity>
        <activity android:name="_SQLconnect"></activity>
        <activity android:name="_TagReader"></activity>
        <activity android:name="_TagReader_Refresh"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Test_mymaxActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the error i get is:
ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=test.mymax/.Test_mymaxActivity } from null (pid=17572, uid=2000) requires null

Please help I have no idea on what's wrong

Answer (score 3):

You declared your Test_mymaxActivity twice. Once here

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Test_mymaxActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

and below a second time

```
 <activity android:name="Test_mymaxActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: It's the same. Remove the second definition `<activity android:name="Test_mymaxActivity"></activity>` from your manifest

Comment: you're right, thank you! But I have another problem, after I unplug my phone from the pc, and I start the app, it says it's waiting for the debugger to attach.. didn't have that one before

Comment: its better to file a new question

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the Intent/Code you are using that is requesting the permission? Or is this immediately on launching your activity?

Comment: there is no answer here, this should be posted as a comment.

Comment: On launching the activity. can't start the app at all

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you declared all the permission needed for your code (**using internet, detect phone state, etc**)

Here's the documentation : [Manifest permission - Android dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html)

Comment: yes, the app worked about 2 mins ago, i changed the '.Test_mymaxActivity' property to 'splash' by accident, saved and built, since then it's not working at all even I changed it back